# Upgrading magento 1.9.3.4 to 1.9.3.6 using magento connect

Tags: magento, console, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade magento 1.9.3.4 to 1.9.3.6 latest using magento connect, but when ever I do upgrade Mage_all_latest Mage_All_Latest in the console it stuck at

```
Checking dependencies of packages
Checking dependencies of packages
```

Any solution would be appreciated, I have tried php 7.1 and php 5.5 same problem persists on both.

Answer (score 0):

This error occur because of some extensions are not supported your server PHP version. So I suggest you instead of upgrade the Magento using Magento connect try to do it manually.